# Package files in separate archives by size

Tags: windows-7, zip

I want to create several **seperate** zip files ("spanned" archives like `archive.z01`, `archive.z02` etc will *not work*) for a given set of files in a folder.

I am not aware that 7z or WinRar could pull this off automatically, so I am left to my own devices (Windows 7 batch I guess?).

How might I do this? I can install any (free) software if necessary, but would like to do it with batch/power shell and 7z, because I already have that...

Comment: Are you not able to installed paid software? Why can't you show us what you've tried then we can help :)

Comment: @Dave Well yes, but I'd rather not make a big fuss about it -  involving IT generally makes it take longer than needed, so I think a small batch script will be more helpful.... as for what I've tried: Nothing besides the "normal" stripping features of 7z and WinRar, then realising it doesn't work and googling how to make "real" archives automated...